# Convergence (absolutely) of an improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(\sin x)}{1+\log(\lfloor|x|\rfloor! + 2)} dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(\sin x)}{1+\log(\lfloor|x|\rfloor! + 2)} dx$$

I need to check if this integral is absolutely convergent...
I've shown it's convergent (not absolutely), according dirichlet test.
I think it's conditionally convergent, but I don't know how to prove it.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to estimate $\lfloor|x|\rfloor!$ using Stirling's formula?

Comment: I believe it is zero, since it is an odd function in a symmetric interval.

Comment: @Fantini But then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx = 0$ which is only true in a sense, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^{n} x dx = 0$, but (what you would expect to be the same integral) $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^{2n} x dx$ does not exist

Comment: @CameronJWhitehead You're right, it's zero in the Cauchy principal value sense. Guess we get no additional insights from it.

Comment: @5xum I will try Stirling's formula, great idea.